Best path search on DEXes
I'm currently working on a project that involves implementing a best path searcher for multi-hop swaps in JavaScript. Specifically, I'm looking for a code sample or library that can efficiently find the optimal sequence of trades across different exchanges or liquidity pools to exploit arbitrage opportunities.
Could anyone provide me with a code example or recommend a library that includes a pathfinding algorithm suitable for this task? I'm particularly interested in solutions that consider factors like transaction fees, slippage, and liquidity constraints.
Thank you in advance for any assistance or guidance you can provide!

See Uniswap Autorouter.

Uniswap smart router Github repository

